# Stata: dividing up the results, variables, and command boxes into 3

Tags: windows, stata

I use Stata SE 11.1 on a Windows XP machine.  I normally prefer to have the results, variables, and command boxes as three distinct boxes that are all visible at the same time.  I accidentally clicked on something that merged them into one display and only lets me toggle between the three, showing only one at a time.

The first image below shows how I prefer it to look whereas the second one shows how it currently looks.  How may I get the display to go the way that I prefer?

This is an image of the preferred display:

[image: Preferred Stata Display]

Above, is the preferred display.

Below, is the current display that I would like no longer.

[image: Not Preferred Stata Display]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Edit, go to Preferences, then Load Preference Set, then Factory Settings.  If your preferred set up was the way Stata was initially set up, then this will get you there.  Good luck!